# How to do Flutter BLE device background communication?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an application for android in flutter. There is a BLE device which communicates with this application and I used flutter_reactive_ble package for BLE communication and its work best for my requirement.

It works perfect at the foreground. I have a requirement of some BLE services to work at background. I want BLE communication to happen even thought app is running at background.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach or a solution?

Comment: You can use the WorkManager package: `https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager`

Comment: I used this but  Its does not work proper for scan BLE.